# How to make element's width match text width with CSS

Tags: css

I have an element that takes 100% of its container's width:

[image]

How do I make it so the width of the element is as wide as the text?

I can't find the answer online because I don't know how to formulate the question proprely.

`float: left;` works but it messes up the surrounding elements as some of them have this porperty as well. Is there another way?

Comment: display:table ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `display: inline-block` OR `display: inline` (depends on your use case) for the element containing the text like so :

```css
.text {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  background: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text</div>

<div class="text">text text text</div>
```